# nginx permanent move not registered by the browser

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

We had a "beta" site set up under http://beta.domain.com, while http://www.domain.com contained a launch page. We now got rid of the launch page and moved the site over to the actual domain. I set up a permanent redirect in nginx to deal with this, but it somehow is not redirecting properly.

```
server {
    server_name beta.domain.com;

    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 permanent;

}
```

When I test it out using curl, it seems to work as expected.

```
$ curl -v beta.domain.com/page
> GET /page HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: beta.domain.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.2.1
< Date: Tue, 16 Jul 2013 20:37:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 184
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.domain.com/page
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I go to `http://beta.domain.com/page` in Firefox, I get redirected to `http://www.domain.com` instead of `http://www.domain.com/page`. If I go directly to `http://www.domain.com/page` in Firefox, that works as expected.

I want to fix this with proper permanent redirect for SEO, but can't figure out the cause of this issue. We are using a Python/Django deployment running on Apache/ModWSGI, with nginx as the frontend server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`return`](http://nginx.org/r/return) instead.

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name beta.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing with some rewrites on my server you may have a some unneeded slashes

try
    rewrite ^(.*) scheme://www.domain.com$1 permanent;